# Chapter header spacing, spacing after sections

Tags: spacing, formatting

I am trying to create double spacing throughout this document - after "Chapter 1" and "after Dimension Reduction in Symmetric Spaces", etc. I also want a top margin of an 1 inch. Can anyone tell me how this might be done? Thanks!

I have included the tex code and the pdf output - [test.pdf](http://docdro.id/eM0WFsR)

I also added a pdf below created in Word that has the formatting that I'd to implement in tex - [Chapter 1.pdf](http://docdro.id/a1qFT47)

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\chapterfont{\centering}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \centering \mdseries}
\chapterfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \centering \mdseries}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \centering \mdseries}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage[left=.88in,right=.88in,top=.88in,bottom=.88in,includefoot] {geometry}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\chapter{Dimension Reduction in Symmetric Spaces} \label{chpt:Dim_Red}   \vspace{-15pt}
In this chapter PGA procedures and their computations for data in three   types of manifolds, the space of positive definite matrices, the special   orthogonal group and the unit spheres, are specified and analyzed.
\section{The Space of Positive Definite Matrices, $P(n)$}   \label{sec:pos_def}
\subsection{Geometry of $P(n)$} \label{ssec:posdef_geo}
A real symmetric matrix . . . 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it at any cost. Here is a way to jump in to the Bay of Bengal.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \mdseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \centering \mdseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \centering \mdseries}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \mdseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \centering \mdseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \centering \mdseries}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage[left=.88in,right=.88in,top=.88in,bottom=.88in,includefoot] {geometry}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\chapter{Dimension Reduction in Symmetric Spaces} \label{chpt:Dim_Red}   \vspace{-15pt}
In this chapter PGA procedures and their computations for data in three   types of manifolds, the space of positive definite matrices, the special   orthogonal group and the unit spheres, are specified and analyzed. definite matrices, the special   orthogonal group and the unit spheres, are
%
\section{The Space of Positive Definite Matrices, $P(n)$}   \label{sec:pos_def}
%definite matrices, the special   orthogonal group and the unit spheres, are
%
\subsection{Geometry of $P(n)$} \label{ssec:posdef_geo}
A real symmetric matrix . . . definite matrices, the special   orthogonal group and the unit spheres, are
\end{document}
```

[image]